# ng-table cannot change column value

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

Getting my head around the ng-table in particular for the editable grid. Trying to change a column value in the data object in any row. However the value in the column does not get updated?
In the setEditId function on the controller the $scope.data object seems to be unchanged after an edit:

```
$scope.setEditId = function (pid) {
    $scope.editId = pid;
}
```

How to get the $scope.data object updated after editing?

Plunkr ref:http://plnkr.co/edit/EVfyVm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually displaying the models value via the html "value" attribute. To change the model itself, you have make use of the **ngModel** directive.

To keep save and cancel functionality, I'd advise to make a working copy in *$scope.edit* using *angular.copy()* of the model *p* and save it back after clicking *save* - though, you can't just overwrite the model with the copy itself, you have to write back every single attribute.

e.g.:

```
p.ln = $scope.edit.ln;
...
```

Instead of:

```
p = $scope.edit;
```

See: http://plnkr.co/edit/rjdEe3